# Ошибка при использование get() в requests

Tags: python, requests

Не могу понять в чем дело, почему когда использую `[x.get('game') for x in onCheck.json()]` для нахождения местоположения игрока, выходит ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CoinsBot.py", line 22, in <module>
    test = [x.get('game') for x in onCheck.json()]
  File "CoinsBot.py", line 22, in <listcomp>
    test = [x.get('game') for x in onCheck.json()]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Мой код:

```
import requests, os, time, json, pyautogui
# Документация по ссылке: api.vime.world

nickname = input(" Ваш ник: ")
findId = requests.get("https://api.vime.world/user/name/" +nickname)

playerId = [x.get('id') for x in findId.json()]
onCheck = requests.get("https://api.vime.world/user/" +str(findId)+ "/session")
print(playerId)

test = [x.get('game') for x in onCheck.json()]

print(test)
```

JSON ответ:

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 4055875,
    "username": "SlavatarAgent",
    "level": 19,
    "levelPercentage": 0.894,
    "rank": "PLAYER",
    "playedSeconds": 3106732,
    "guild": 19181
  },
  "online": {
    "value": true,
    "message": "Находится в Лобби",
    "game": "LOBBY"
  }
}
```

Comment: пофикси `str(findId)` на `str(playerId[0])`, `findId` же сам ответ у тебя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы делаете `for x in onCheck.json()`, то вы перебираете ключи словаря, которые являются строками. Далее вы вызываете метод `get()` у ключей (строк), хотя нужно вызывать метод у значений, находящихся под этими ключами.

И еще, для того, чтобы получить значение `game`, вам не обязательно обходить все элементы словаря. Вы можете получить нужное значение напрямую:

```
onCheck.json()['online'].get('game')
```

Подробнее:

```
In [29]: onCheck.json()
Out[29]: 
{'user': {'id': 4055875,
  'username': 'SlavatarAgent',
  'level': 19,
  'levelPercentage': 0.02763,
  'rank': 'PLAYER',
  'playedSeconds': 528267,
  'lastSeen': 1567012401,
  'guild': {'id': 19181,
   'name': 'VellixsTeam',
   'tag': None,
   'color': '&f',
   'level': 2,
   'levelPercentage': 0.932533,
   'avatar_url': None}},
 'online': {'value': True, 'message': 'Играет в SkyWars Solo', 'game': 'SW'}}

In [30]: for x in onCheck.json():
    ...:     print(x, type(x))
    ...:     
user <class 'str'>
online <class 'str'>

In [31]: onCheck.json()['online'].get('game')
Out[31]: 'SW'

In [32]: onCheck.json()['online'].get('message')
Out[32]: 'Играет в SkyWars Solo'

In [33]: onCheck.json()['user'].get('username')
Out[33]: 'SlavatarAgent'
```

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка говорит нам о том что нельзя использовать get() с переменными `string`, попробуйте заменить тип переменной

Requests: https://khashtamov.com/ru/python-requests/